# Function will not execute inside while loop

Tags: python, function

I am fairly new to python and am struggling with getting a function to work inside a while loop. For what ever reason it will work if I place it before the while loop as seen below:

This works:

```
async def connect_and_listen(self, retry_count=0, max_retries=5, backoff_factor=1):
    if not self.initialized:
        await self.fetch_depth_snapshot()
        await self.process_buffered_messages()
        
    while self.running and retry_count < max_retries:
        try:
            self.websocket = await websockets.connect(self.uri)
            await self.stomp_connect()
            await self.listen_to_messages()
            await self.subscribe_to_streams()
            retry_count = 0  # Reset retry count on successful connection

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Connection error: {e}")
            retry_count += 1
            sleep_time = backoff_factor * (2 ** retry_count)
            logging.info(f"Retrying connection in {sleep_time} seconds.")
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
```

This doesn't:

```
async def connect_and_listen(self, retry_count=0, max_retries=5, backoff_factor=1):  
    while self.running and retry_count < max_retries:
        try:
            self.websocket = await websockets.connect(self.uri)
            await self.stomp_connect()
            await self.listen_to_messages()
            await self.subscribe_to_streams()
            retry_count = 0  # Reset retry count on successful connection
            if not self.initialized:
                await self.fetch_depth_snapshot()
                await self.process_buffered_messages()
      
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Connection error: {e}")
            retry_count += 1
            sleep_time = backoff_factor * (2 ** retry_count)
            logging.info(f"Retrying connection in {sleep_time} seconds.")
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Note the other 3 functions in the while loop execute just fine. You may ask why I dont just leave it at the position that works? Well I actually need it to execute after the subscribe_to_streams function completes so I dont miss any of the messages from the websocket.

I have tried placing the function call in different places including other functions in the class but no matter where I put it, it only works in the one position I showed above. What I expected to happen was the function to execute successfully, how do I know it doesnt work? The data is pushed to a webpage via a Flask appplication and it works fine in the 'good' spot but shows no data for any other position. I have also added print messages throughout the code (removed for clarity now) to try and determine where the issue lies but all that did was reinforce the fact the function is never being called.

Also I just want to say thank you ahead of time for your patience and time, please let me know if you need more of my code or if I have posted incorrectly here.

Comment: What function, exactly, is not working?  There are lots of function calls here.

Comment: Possibly some function modified "self.initialized" value before hit that if block. Check following function snippet: await self.stomp_connect(), await self.listen_to_messages(),  await self.subscribe_to_streams()

Comment: You can add print statement before If block , You will get True or some values on that

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, these are the functions that are not working:
        await self.fetch_depth_snapshot()
        await self.process_buffered_messages()